# Como mostrar dados em ordem crescente mongoosejs + expressjs

Tags: node.js, express.js

Olá pessoal poderia me ajudar? Estou tentando mostrar meus registros do Banco de Dados em ordem crescente, porém trata-se de um objeto dentro de outro e quero organizar por cashOut segue a foto do meu DB.
[image: Meu banco de dados]

Estou usando o mongoose e expressjs segue abaixo como estou buscando os dados:

```
    var Serial = function(){
    this.sumTotalBets = function(game){
        var totalBet = 0;
        game.findOne({gameStatus:'in progress'}, function(err, games){
            if(err){throw err}
            for(var i = 0; i < games.players.length; i++){
                totalBet += Number(games.players[i].bet);
            }
            totalBet = totalBet.toFixed(8);
            console.log('Soma de tudo ' + totalBet);

            for(i = 0; i < games.players.length; i++){
                var verify = Number(games.players[i].profit);
                if(totalBet > verify.toFixed(8)){
                    totalBet -= verify;
                    console.log('Continua ' + i + ' ' + totalBet.toFixed(8));
                }else{
                    console.log('Parou em ' + i + ' ' + totalBet.toFixed(8) + ' PayOut ' + (games.players[i].cashOut - 0.01).toFixed(2));
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
module.exports = new Serial();
```

RESULTADO NO CONSOLE

```
Soma de tudo 0.00263300
Continua 0 0.00262765
Continua 1 0.00252380
Parou em 2 0.00252380 PayOut 100.98
Continua 3 0.00252180
Parou em 4 0.00252180 PayOut 1.99`
```

**Resumindo quero listar players por cashOut em ondem crescente**

Answer (score 0):

Se um objeto for passado, os valores permitidos são
 `are asc, desc, ascending, descending, 1,` and `-1`

Veja a [documentação official](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort):

```
// mostre field" ascendente e "test" descendente
query.sort({ field: 'asc', test: -1 });
```

Por exemplo:

```
{'cashOut', 'asc'}
```

Obs.: Quando voce não especifica o sort (1, -1, etc), ele trabalha em ordem ascendente.